# Conda list has pyparsing but I got ImportError: No module named pyparsing

Tags: python, anaconda, pyparsing

My `conda list` has pyparsing

```
pyparsing                 2.1.4                    py27_0
```

But when I ran python file which has

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I got error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "170509-NMF002(stfml)_003.py", line 31, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/Users/jan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 124, in <module>
    from matplotlib.rcsetup import (defaultParams,
  File "/Users/jan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/rcsetup.py", line 32, in <module>
    from matplotlib.fontconfig_pattern import parse_fontconfig_pattern
  File "/Users/jan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/fontconfig_pattern.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pyparsing import Literal, ZeroOrMore, \
ImportError: No module named pyparsing
```

How to fix this error?

Additional detail: It should not be related but I just did `pip uninstall pyparsing` as I accidentally installed ipykernel via pip (and ipykernel installed another pyparsing). I uninstalled all that packages due to that mistake. Anyway, I installed anaconda first and pyparsing is still here.

Comment: This is really more a conda issue. But if you can get it resolved, please upgrade to pyparsing version 2.2 or later. There are some important bug fixes and enhancements in versions released after 2.1.4.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire I ran `conda update pyparsing` now, and it is still 2.1.4. How to make conda update to the version after this?

Comment: 2.1.4 is the latest version available in the default Anaconda channel.

Comment: It would be good to get the default Anaconda channel to reflect pyparsing 2.2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Remove pyparsing using

```
conda uninstall pyparsing
```

Then reinstall the more recent version (2.2.0) from the conda-forge channel.

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyparsing
```